# C# equivalent of Java's KDFCounterBytesGenerator (from bouncycastle)

Tags: java, c#, bouncycastle

I want to port this code to C#

```
byte[] result = new byte[length];
byte[] data = ...;
byte[] key = ...;

HMac hMac = new HMac(new SHA256Digest());
KDFCounterBytesGenerator g = new KDFCounterBytesGenerator(hMac);
g.init(new KDFCounterParameters(key, data, 32));
g.generateBytes(result , 0, result .length);
```

But I can't find any equivalent classes in C# bouncycastle library.
Any advice?

Edit:
I ported the KDFCounterBytesGenerator from the Java source and it worked fine..

Comment: I see you've ported the implementation from Java. Could you share the code, please?

Answer (score -1):

[BouncyCastle has an equivalent library for C#](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) that should contain most if not all of the same features as it's Java version with some minor syntax differences:

[image]

You should be able to install it via NuGet and then reference it accordingly :

```
// Using statements (for BouncyCastle)
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Generators;

// Define your byte[]s
byte[] result = new byte[1];
byte[] data = new byte[2];
byte[] key = new byte[3];

// Build your HMac, Generator and generate your bytes
HMac hMac = new HMac(new Sha256Digest());
Kdf1BytesGenerator g = new Kdf1BytesGenerator(hMac.GetUnderlyingDigest());
g.Init(new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.KdfParameters(key, data));
g.GenerateBytes(result, 0, result.Length);
```

Comment: This is not worked for me. The results are different!

Comment: You may consider trying the `Kdf2BytesGenerator` class as well as it may have different results. I haven't worked with BouncyCastle in quite some time or used the methods that you are specifying, but I would assume that equivalents exist. I've updated the example to use an `HMac` object, which might have an affect